# Node.js create-react-app build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, glassfish, create-react-app

I am pretty new to web development and I was asked to create a single-page application with tools of my choice. The only requirement is that it has to run locally on a GlassFish server (in NetBeans: Java Web > Web Application). I use the create-react-app starter kit provided by Facebook to build the application. When I run `npm run build` I get a build folder containing an html-file and a js-file. But when I double-click the html-file, the browser opens and just shows an empty page. Does anyone know what I have to configure in order to get a bundled html-file that shows the application when I open it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: I think you would have tried, https://jhipster.github.io/ scafolding tool to generate JAVA, AngularJS, * Databases

Comment: The browser console did not print any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running "`npm run build`" on your create-react-app generated code, it displays instructions to help with just this. It says something like:

```
You may also serve it locally with a static server:

npm install -g pushstate-server
pushstate-server build
```

The first command, "`npm install -g pushstate-server`" only needs to be run once, as it installs "pushstate-server" to global NPM.  The second command "`pushstate-server build`" runs the simple static server, pushstate-server, and serves up any content in the "build" folder at http://localhost:9000. You can change the port number if you wish, by adding it at end of command line: "`pushstate-server build 1234`"

**UDPATE: Serverless method...**

If your goal is to run the page from the file system, and not from a web server, you'll need to tweak the `build/index.html` to fix the paths to your JS and CSS (and less importantly, your favicon.ico). The index.html generated by create-react-app expects your JS and CSS to be at "/static/...".  However, when you open from the file system, that path is not correct. If you remove the leading forward slash, making the URLs relative, your page will load properly from the file system:

After running "npm run build", open the generated "build/index.html" file. Remove the leading forward slash from "/favicon.ico", "/static/js/main.[random string].js" and "/static/css/main.[random string].css" and save your changes (so that the all read "static/..." and not "/static/..."). Reload/refresh the page in the browser.

Comment: Thank you, but do I need this pushstate-server every time I want to view the build? My goal is to build an html/js-package that I can simply distribute to anyone and that is independent from Node.js.

Comment: Yes, using the above method would require that your end user is running some sort of static HTTP server. However, there is a way to do what you're looking for.  I will modify my answer to include the following suggesting... After running "npm run build", open the generated "build/index.html" file. Remove the leading forward slash from "/favicon.ico", "/static/js/main.[randomstring].js" and "static/css/main.[random string].css" and save your changes.  Double clicking the index.html should then load

Comment: I removed the leading forward slashes and it works, however other resources like images or icons do not appear in the application. Seems like their paths are not relative and they are hidden somewhere inside the js-file. I found them but the paths are generated by string concatenation so they are not that easy to manipulate. Do you know how to configure create-react-app/webpack to make all paths relative?

Comment: create-react-app intentionally only allows "minimal configuration" unless you eject ("npm run eject"). After you eject, you can customize webpack.